# admob is not displaying any ad on android app

Tags: android, admob

Admob is not working correctly when putting my banner id, but it's working when adding debug banner id for testing, any help ?

XML code

```
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Java code

```
 MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-****************");
    mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

and I have these permission in manifist

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

This is the banner ad that I have is it right ?

[image]

Comment: It usually takes some te for the ad id to get activated after you generate them. Try after sometime.

Comment: did it take day or week ?

Comment: Atmost 1.5 days

Comment: can you check the image that I have uploaded, is everything right ??

Comment: yes everything is right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because I wasn't setting my payment address in admob.

Comment: This issue is faced by me at yesterday only because they can't serving the ads without verification and aading the payment after sometimes of given days. Before that in 2017, 2016 their is no any terms and conditions like this at that time all things will be taken lightly but now its to much strict. other wise i have so much idea regarding the admob. https://www.facebook.com/DarshanInstitute.Official/photos/pcb.881866588620064/881866535286736/?type=3&theater

Answer (score 0):

If the debug ads shows up, then your implementation is correct. Sometimes ads don't show up until they get released (not always true). But yeah it does take a while for google to find the right ads for your app. Be patient

Comment: thank you for your reply, i have published my application into play store as beta version